# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module processed.commons.exec not found,

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

```
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class FirstSeleniumProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\amar\\Documents\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
        
        chrome.get("https://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

Very first program and I am getting this error.

I installed TestNG per some recommendations. When that did not work, I removed the https:// from the link and it gave me the following error:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module processed.async.http.client not found, required by org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver

Comment: be sure to add all of Selenium's dependencies.  Sounds like you're missing those.

Comment: How are you managing your dependencies?

Comment: I downloaded the latest from selenium.dev. The version was 4.7.2 I believe. I imported all the files from the folder and the files from the "lib" folder into the modulepath for the package. Is that what you guys mean?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue by deleting all the selenium jar files from the modulepath and adding them all to the classpath instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error for me was with the Java version. While making the project make sure you choose Java 1.8 (or maybe an even lower version).

And if you are using the selenium zip file to add to the build path,
make sure you add the lib folder separately.

Answer (score 0):

I faced such type of issue earlier when i configure selenium webdriver first time with eclipse, that time i update my java version to 17 so because of this such issue comes so, to overcome this i just simply change java version to 8 from project ....its working propely now

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on project name, go to build path>configure build path> libraries, remove method libraries and select add and select JRE System libraries.

Answer (score 0):

We can fix this by adding jar files under classpath , remove jar files from module path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).